# I want to upload image with other parameters to server using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, post, image-uploading

well am new to iOS and i encountered a situation where i have to upload a image to server. Here is what am doing in the post method.

```
- (IBAction)submitClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSDictionary *inputData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myImage,@"coverPic", nil];

NSError *error;
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.mapartment.in/index.php/events/create"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:70.0];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *jsonInputData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:inputData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSString *jsonInputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonInputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPBody:[jsonInputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSDictionary *jsondictcity_name = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];

        if([[jsondictcity_name valueForKey:@"result"] isEqual:@"true"]){

            NSLog(@"Success");

        }

        else{

            NSLog(@"Try Again");
        }

        [self.view resignFirstResponder];

    });
}

                                      ];
[postDataTask resume];

}
```

P.S. _localFilePath contains - /Users/appcode/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3C3567B8-03BC-4233-B0BC-97E3899D0AAA/data/Containers/Data/Application/3D574024-42FB-4305-807A-ACC3C128383F/Documents/png

Comment: i think you first need to get image using path

Comment: down in the P.S. i was getting the path of the image and i was storing that path in _localFilePath (NSString type) and passing it with key @"coverPic"

Answer (score 1):

Image will not pass with other parameter,you have to convert image into NSData

```
   UIImage *yourImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
   NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
   NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [imageData length]];
```

and then pass these data in request

```
 [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [request setHTTPBody:imageData];
```

and other parameter pass as json.

to get UIImage from path use

```
 UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imageFilePath];
```

Comment: i got the concept but am confused about where to place the codes. So will you help me to edit my above code with the image upload method suggested by you because as you can see i have a key named as - coverPic. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)submitClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:_localFilePath];
    NSString *myImage = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    NSDictionary *inputData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myImage,@"coverPic",@"POEM WRITING",@"title",@"Bring your own paper",@"desc", nil];

    NSError *error;
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.mapartment.in/index.php/events/create"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
    timeoutInterval:70.0];

    [request addValue:@"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSData *jsonInputData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:inputData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    NSString *jsonInputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonInputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [request setHTTPBody:[jsonInputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    NSDictionary *jsondictcity_name = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];

    if([[jsondictcity_name valueForKey:@"result"] isEqual:@"true"]){

    NSLog(@"Success");

    }

    else{

    NSLog(@"Try Again");
    }

    [self.view resignFirstResponder];

    });
    }

    ];
    [postDataTask resume];

    }
```

Comment: so what to attach with the key @"coverPic" ?

Comment: app crashed on the line - [NSString stringWithString: _localFilePath] ]; with error - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'
BTW thanks for your support

Comment: well i think the uploading is happening because the response am getting is after 20-30 seconds but when i check api on postman the coverPic parameter shows nil

Comment: are getting any response like success or failed?

Comment: well am going in success block but when i check the listing API i find the coverPic parameter as empty which means the image was not uploaded.

Comment: please check myImage empty or not

Comment: myImage contains a base64 url. Its not empty. BTW i consulted one of my android friend and he suggested me to send the path of the image. Are we doing somthing like that

Comment: @Hemant in ios side not possible to send path.we need to send image using nsdata or base64

Comment: wait i will try your code if image upload pls check in list data

Comment: @Hemant your api give response like this {
    error = "Please Check send_to_type";
    result = false;
}

Comment: change multipart/form-data to application/json

Comment: also check my edited code because i have given now all the parameters